# How I can use an already existing table in SQL Server with ApplicationDbContext.cs

Tags: entity-framework-core, blazor, ef-database-first

I am using Blazor, EF Core, NET 6, SQL Server.

I created one database and a table in SQL Server LocalDB (DB: `MyCompany`, Table: `SalaryTax_2023`)

`SalaryTax_2023` has the tax amount of money according to each salary.

And I set up an `ApplicationDbContext.cs` and `Program.cs`, `appsettings.json` and all (ApplicationDbContext doesn't yet have any `DbSet`).

I created a method to get the `salarytax` with user input variables:

```
result = await dbContext
                    .SalaryTax_2023
                    .Where(row => row.min <= salary && salary < row.max)
                    .Select(row => new TaxResult { TaxAmount = row[columnIndex] })
                    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

But I can't access `SalaryTax_2023`. It might I tried to access to a database without `DbSet`.

As far as I know, I can use it because its table already had schema  and data itself. How can I access for this case?

I have learned that migration & `update-database` command is for the synchronization between EF Core and Blazor.

I hope I could get the clue or answer how I can solve this problem.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/designer/workflows/database-first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can execute raw SQL queries to interact with the table directly. This allows you to execute SQL queries and map the results to C# objects. Check this out:

```
using var dbContext = new ApplicationDbContext();

var salary = 50000; // The salary you want to query for
var query = $"SELECT * FROM SalaryTax_2023 WHERE min <= {salary} AND max > {salary}";
var result = await 
dbContext.SalaryTax_2023.FromSqlRaw(query).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

or, you can create a db set:

```
public DbSet<SalaryTax_2023> SalaryTax_2023 { get; set; }
```

This DbSet doesn't require migrations since it represents an existing table

```
var result = await dbContext
.SalaryTax_2023
.Where(row => row.min <= salary && salary < row.max)
.Select(row => new TaxResult { TaxAmount = row[columnIndex] })
.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But if I have to make migration with other dbset which is needed later, isn't it effect to the schema of exited SalaryTax_2023 tables? Because of this I didn't try dbset before.

Comment: if you have an existing SalaryTax_2023 table in the database and you add a new DbSet to the ApplicationDbContext class that maps to the SalaryTax_2023 table, Entity Framework Core will not overwrite the existing SalaryTax_2023 table. Instead, Entity Framework Core will simply start tracking the SalaryTax_2023 table, you can safely run the migrations and update-database commands without affecting the existing SalaryTax_2023 table

Comment: Of course, it is always a good idea to back up your database before running the migrations and update-database commands

Comment: Thank you. I will try it according to your advice. @Gogu32Hz